# Xamarin Forms carousel with menu/tabs

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, carousel, tabbedpage

I want do create something like TabbedPage but as a View with scrollable "menu" ( I will have about 8 tabs). How can I achive this? I was thinking about doing CarouselView and somehow to make a tabbed header, but I dont know how to make it good. Or maybe there is a plugin for TabbedView ( I spent few hours and I didn't find anything). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

James Montemagno made a a brilliant [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/) on how to implement this a couple of years ago.

That sorts out the Carousel View. Now to write the tabbed header I wrote 1 of these a couple of years back. What you need to do is make a stacklayout with orientation horizontal, make the width bigger than the screen width and then every new page you visit you can translate the top bars x coordinates to the left or right. and change the image in the bar so that it looks highlighted.

Have a real play with this, see if you can make the transitions between pages smooth and the translation look sleek. I managed to do it so Im sure you will be fine.

I would provide code but unfortunately it was for a client and I cannot share his intellectual property.

Comment: Will try. Thank you so much!

Comment: That link is dead now, but I think you were pointing to this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms does not provide a TabView control but only a TabbedPage which seems to be no good in your case. There are commercial third party libraries that offer such a control out of the box (e.g. from SyncFusion).  I looked quite a long time into this issue. Finally, I went for creating my own implementation which is based on a data bindable StackLayout with a horizontal line of buttons. Only the ContentView that is associated with the selected button is shown all other ones are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link on the old Xamarin forums [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69260/cool-demo-of-carouselview-with-pseudo-sliding-tabs-strip-at-top-and-toolbar-at-bottom)

I think this is exactly what you're looking for here. I had do a few things to get the sample to run like upgrade the version of Xamarin.Forms, then delete the nuget package for carousel view prerelease since its since rolled in with Xamarin.Forms.

[image]